# Казахские буквы в iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Пишу что-то вроде:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("Helv Kaz.ttf", "cp1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(baseFont, Font.DEFAULTSIZE, Font.NORMAL);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
document.open();
document.add(new Phrase("Жәбірейіл",font));
document.close();
```

В результате получаю, например, Жбірейіл вместо Жәбірейіл, что я делаю не так?

Comment: как вариант, изменить кодировку

Comment: cp1251 не поддерживает казахские буквы. Нужно utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуй так :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    final String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf";
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
    Font font = new Font(baseFont);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Z:/test.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Phrase("Жәбірейіл", font));
    document.close();
}
```